# c# SQL Listview selected item comparison to column

Tags: c#, sql

what I'm trying to do is when I select an item on my `listview1`, then compare that value to the value in my datatable column, and then put that `osztalyzatok` column in the `listview3` where the `listview1` selected item equals to the `id_tanulo`

Here is my code:

[image]

And my Datatable:

[image]

Comment: Try to use `Listview1.SelectedIndices[0].toString()` instead of  `Listview1.SelectedIndices` if you want to compare single selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Listview1.SelectedIndices[0].toString()` instead of `Listview1.SelectedIndices` if you want to compare single selected value.

`Listview1.SelectedIndices` Is array type and it contains list of selected Items in ListView.

Comment: I get an exception error message now:
InvalidArgument = Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'
Parameter name: index

Comment: If you are comparing single value I will suggest you to use `SelectedIndex`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but listview control doesnt have SelectedIndex property, only SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: may be I missing something, ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.selectedindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx